# ZSH Custom Prompt

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

So I'm trying to find a way to create a custom prompt, or rather, modify the one that comes with `candy` zsh theme. I made it like this:

```
PROMPT=$'%{$fg_bold[red]%}User@%m %{$fg[blue]%}%D{[%X]} %{$reset_color%}%{$fg[white]%}[%~]%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)\
%{$fg_bold[blue]%} %{^%{$reset_color%} '
```

However, when I paste a command in the terminal, last two characters get duplicated. The thing I modified was `%{^%{$reset_color%}` and I'm pretty sure I got that one wrong. All I wanted was a `^` symbol in a new line, instead of candy default, which is `-> %` or something similar.